# Reading a lot of data from the internet

Tags: java, android, json

I am currently working on a project for my portfolio. I having a little trouble trying to find the right solution to this problem mainly because I have never tried it before.

I am using a free `API` service that I found online. I have created the database to match all the information, and not I just need to download the information and parse into my application.

I have parsed data from the `API`  **`(JSON)`** and into my database. A couple of suggestions that I have found is reading 10 records at a time, but I want to try reading everything at once and then updating accordingly (let us say every 24 hours).

The `APi` I am using is the a free Game of Thrones `API` and below is the list I want of about the URL is formed to access each part data as I move through it.

- https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/
- https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/books/
- https://anapioficeandfire.com/api/houses/

At the end of the each of these `URLS` is a number that indicates the record number that I am trying to get. I have done this before while get information from a single page, and the page contained multiple `JSON` object. This time I need to move through multiple pages to get the single object on that page.

To give you an idea of the steps that I am looking for :

- Go the page
- Download the Information
- Move on the next page
- Break when there when I have reached the end.